# NHibernate Linq over a dictionary

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I have a following excerpt of my domain (and FNH mapping)

```
public class Product
{
  public virtual int Id { get; set; }
  public virtual string Name { get; set; }        
  public virtual IDictionary<LimSet, string> Attributes { get; set; }
  /*equality logic there*/
}

public class LimSet
{
  virtual public int Id { get; set; }
  public virtual string Name { get; set; }
  /*equality logic there*/
}                

internal class LimSetMap : ClassMap<LimSet>
{
  public LimSetMap()
  {
      Table("LIMSET");
      Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Assigned();
      Map(x => x.Name);
  }
}
internal class ProductMap : ClassMap<Product>
{
  public ProductMap()
  {
      Table("PRODUCT");
      Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Assigned();
      Map(x => x.Name);            
      HasMany(x => x.Attributes)
          .AsEntityMap("LIMSET_ID")
          .Table("PRODUCT_ATTR")
          .KeyColumn("PRODUCT_ID")
          .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
          .Element("VALUE");
  }   
}
```

The issue is with map (dictionary) of components (simple string value so far) using another entity as a key. Everything seems ok, e.g. I can generate database schema, also I can manipulate the dictionary and save it with cascade. When I query the Attributes dictionary using

```
var prodWithAttrs = session.Query<Product>()
  .Where(p => p.Id == 1)
  .SelectMany(p => p.Attributes,
     (p, a) => new
               {
                 Product = p.Name,
                 Attribute = a.Key.Name,
                 Value = a.Value
               });
```

I'm getting an exception

`` cannot dereference scalar collection element: Key [.SelectMany[Domain.Product,System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[... ``

I've tried several options how to rephrase the query but without success. Do you know if something like this is possible with current (3.3.2) NH Linq provider?

Many thanks

Comment: I just upgraded from NH 2.2 to 3.3.2 and have the same error with SelectMany queries that were previously working just fine...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps you...

I just upgraded from NH 2.2 to 3.3.2 and I get the same error with certain SelectMany queries that were previously working just fine in NH 2.2 with the NH.Linq provider.

My NH 2.2 (working) queries were of the form:

```
Session.Query<T>().SelectMany(o => o.DictionaryProperty.Values)
```

and I'd get the following error in NH 3.3.2:

```
cannot dereference scalar collection element: Values
```

I was able to get it working by changing the query to:

```
Session.Query<T>().SelectMany(o => o.DictionaryProperty).ToList().Select(kvp => kvp.Value)
```

Which effectively moves the dictionary value access out of Linq-to-NHibernate and into Linq-to-Objects. Not yet sure what's going on here...